# null value in column "jti" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, integration, rails-api, devise-jwt

i already search in google for the answer but the only solution i can find is to include this
" include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher " on my user.rb which i already is.

im doing a rails test in interation for user registration but it keeps on giving me this error even though i also tried to generate it manually.

my whole error is this:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "jti" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (980190962, , , null, null, null, 2024-03-06 05:51:33.711982, 2024-03-06 05:51:33.711982, null).
```

i generally want  to solve my test error. i see no problem when i tried the api and see the jti in the database isnt null.

Comment: Add the failing test -- there is not enough information to allow anyone to help.